# Mysql query multiple tables and inner join

Tags: php, sql, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have 3 tables and I want to have a query that gives me the sum of the sales, the sum of the deposits and the difference between them, try this but the records are duplicated.

this is my query:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.9.11
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Servidor: localhost:3306
-- Tiempo de generación: 28-11-2023 a las 16:25:38
-- Versión del servidor: 5.6.41-84.1
-- Versión de PHP: 7.4.33

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Base de datos: `geasacpe_consolidado`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `articulo`
--

CREATE TABLE `articulo` (
  `id_articulo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nombre_articulo` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `precio` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `id_local` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `articulo`
--

INSERT INTO `articulo` (`id_articulo`, `nombre_articulo`, `precio`, `id_local`) VALUES
(1, 'PREMIUN AVENTURERO', '10.00', 1),
(2, 'REGULAR AVENTURERO', '8.00', 1),
(3, 'GLP AVENTURERO', '5.00', 1),
(4, 'PREMIUN EL FIEL', '12.00', 2),
(5, 'REGULAR EL FIEL', '9.00', 2),
(6, 'GLP EL FIEL', '4.00', 2);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `contometro`
--

CREATE TABLE `contometro` (
  `id_contometro` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fecha_contometro` date NOT NULL,
  `turno_contometro` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `inicial_contometro` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `final_contometro` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `precio_articulo` decimal(10,3) NOT NULL,
  `id_local` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_manguera` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_punto` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_lado` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_articulo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_vendedor` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `contometro`
--

INSERT INTO `contometro` (`id_contometro`, `fecha_contometro`, `turno_contometro`, `inicial_contometro`, `final_contometro`, `precio_articulo`, `id_local`, `id_manguera`, `id_punto`, `id_lado`, `id_articulo`, `id_vendedor`) VALUES
(3, '2023-11-28', 1, 0, 10, '10.000', 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
(4, '2023-11-28', 1, 0, 8, '8.000', 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1),
(5, '2023-11-28', 1, 0, 12, '5.000', 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1),
(6, '2023-11-28', 1, 0, 13, '10.000', 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `depositoxvendedor`
--

CREATE TABLE `depositoxvendedor` (
  `id_depositoxvendedor` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fecha_depositoxvendedor` date NOT NULL,
  `turno_depositoxvendedor` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `numero_depositoxvendedor` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `monto_depositoxvendedor` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `id_tipopago` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_vendedor` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_local` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `depositoxvendedor`
--

INSERT INTO `depositoxvendedor` (`id_depositoxvendedor`, `fecha_depositoxvendedor`, `turno_depositoxvendedor`, `numero_depositoxvendedor`, `monto_depositoxvendedor`, `id_tipopago`, `id_vendedor`, `id_local`) VALUES
(1, '2023-11-28', 1, 1, '100.00', 1, 1, 1),
(2, '2023-11-28', 1, 2, '150.00', 2, 1, 1),
(3, '2023-11-28', 1, 3, '50.00', 1, 2, 1),
(4, '2023-11-28', 1, 4, '30.00', 2, 2, 1);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `lado`
--

CREATE TABLE `lado` (
  `id_lado` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `numero_lado` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_punto` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_local` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `lado`
--

INSERT INTO `lado` (`id_lado`, `numero_lado`, `id_punto`, `id_local`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 1),
(2, 2, 1, 1),
(3, 3, 3, 1),
(4, 4, 3, 1),
(5, 1, 4, 2),
(6, 2, 4, 2),
(7, 3, 2, 2),
(8, 4, 2, 2);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `local`
--

CREATE TABLE `local` (
  `id_local` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nombre_local` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `local`
--

INSERT INTO `local` (`id_local`, `nombre_local`) VALUES
(1, 'AVENTURERO'),
(2, 'EL FIEL INCOMPRENDIDO');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `manguera`
--

CREATE TABLE `manguera` (
  `id_manguera` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `numero_manguera` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_lado` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_articulo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_local` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `manguera`
--

INSERT INTO `manguera` (`id_manguera`, `numero_manguera`, `id_lado`, `id_articulo`, `id_local`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
(2, 2, 1, 2, 1),
(3, 3, 1, 3, 1),
(4, 1, 2, 1, 1),
(5, 2, 2, 2, 1),
(6, 3, 2, 3, 1);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `punto`
--

CREATE TABLE `punto` (
  `id_punto` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `marca_punto` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `modelo_punto` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_local` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `punto`
--

INSERT INTO `punto` (`id_punto`, `marca_punto`, `modelo_punto`, `id_local`) VALUES
(1, 'GILBARCO AVENTURERO', '3000', 1),
(2, 'TOKEIN EL FIEL', '2000', 2),
(3, 'TOKEIN AVENTURERO', '2000', 1),
(4, 'GILBARCO EL FIEL', '3000', 2);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `puntoxvendedor`
--

CREATE TABLE `puntoxvendedor` (
  `id_puntoxvendedor` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fecha_puntoxvendedor` date NOT NULL,
  `turno_puntoxvendedor` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_punto` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_vendedor` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `puntoxvendedor`
--

INSERT INTO `puntoxvendedor` (`id_puntoxvendedor`, `fecha_puntoxvendedor`, `turno_puntoxvendedor`, `id_punto`, `id_vendedor`) VALUES
(1, '2023-11-28', 1, 1, 1),
(2, '2023-11-28', 1, 3, 2);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `vendedor`
--

CREATE TABLE `vendedor` (
  `id_vendedor` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nombre_vendedor` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `id_local` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `vendedor`
--

INSERT INTO `vendedor` (`id_vendedor`, `nombre_vendedor`, `id_local`) VALUES
(1, 'VENDEDOR 1 AVENTURERO', 1),
(2, 'VENDEDOR 2 AVENTURERO', 1),
(3, 'VENDEDOR 1 EL FIEL', 2),
(4, 'VENDEDOR 2 EL FIEL', 2);

--
-- Índices para tablas volcadas
--

--
-- Indices de la tabla `articulo`
--
ALTER TABLE `articulo`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_articulo`),
  ADD KEY `id_local` (`id_local`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `contometro`
--
ALTER TABLE `contometro`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_contometro`),
  ADD KEY `id_local` (`id_local`),
  ADD KEY `id_manguera` (`id_manguera`),
  ADD KEY `id_punto` (`id_punto`),
  ADD KEY `id_lado` (`id_lado`),
  ADD KEY `id_articulo` (`id_articulo`),
  ADD KEY `id_vendedor` (`id_vendedor`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `depositoxvendedor`
--
ALTER TABLE `depositoxvendedor`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_depositoxvendedor`),
  ADD KEY `id_vendedor` (`id_vendedor`),
  ADD KEY `id_local` (`id_local`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `lado`
--
ALTER TABLE `lado`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_lado`),
  ADD KEY `id_punto` (`id_punto`),
  ADD KEY `id_local` (`id_local`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `local`
--
ALTER TABLE `local`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_local`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `manguera`
--
ALTER TABLE `manguera`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_manguera`),
  ADD KEY `id_lado` (`id_lado`),
  ADD KEY `id_articulo` (`id_articulo`),
  ADD KEY `id_local` (`id_local`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `punto`
--
ALTER TABLE `punto`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_punto`),
  ADD KEY `id_local` (`id_local`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `puntoxvendedor`
--
ALTER TABLE `puntoxvendedor`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_puntoxvendedor`),
  ADD KEY `id_punto` (`id_punto`),
  ADD KEY `id_vendedor` (`id_vendedor`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `vendedor`
--
ALTER TABLE `vendedor`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_vendedor`),
  ADD KEY `id_local` (`id_local`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de las tablas volcadas
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `articulo`
--
ALTER TABLE `articulo`
  MODIFY `id_articulo` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=7;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `contometro`
--
ALTER TABLE `contometro`
  MODIFY `id_contometro` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=7;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `depositoxvendedor`
--
ALTER TABLE `depositoxvendedor`
  MODIFY `id_depositoxvendedor` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=5;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `lado`
--
ALTER TABLE `lado`
  MODIFY `id_lado` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=9;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `local`
--
ALTER TABLE `local`
  MODIFY `id_local` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=3;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `manguera`
--
ALTER TABLE `manguera`
  MODIFY `id_manguera` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=7;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `punto`
--
ALTER TABLE `punto`
  MODIFY `id_punto` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=5;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `puntoxvendedor`
--
ALTER TABLE `puntoxvendedor`
  MODIFY `id_puntoxvendedor` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=3;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `vendedor`
--
ALTER TABLE `vendedor`
  MODIFY `id_vendedor` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=5;

--
-- Restricciones para tablas volcadas
--

--
-- Filtros para la tabla `articulo`
--
ALTER TABLE `articulo`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `articulo_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_local`) REFERENCES `local` (`id_local`);

--
-- Filtros para la tabla `contometro`
--
ALTER TABLE `contometro`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `contometro_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_local`) REFERENCES `local` (`id_local`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `contometro_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id_manguera`) REFERENCES `manguera` (`id_manguera`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `contometro_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`id_punto`) REFERENCES `punto` (`id_punto`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `contometro_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`id_lado`) REFERENCES `lado` (`id_lado`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `contometro_ibfk_5` FOREIGN KEY (`id_articulo`) REFERENCES `articulo` (`id_articulo`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `contometro_ibfk_6` FOREIGN KEY (`id_vendedor`) REFERENCES `vendedor` (`id_vendedor`);

--
-- Filtros para la tabla `depositoxvendedor`
--
ALTER TABLE `depositoxvendedor`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `depositoxvendedor_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_vendedor`) REFERENCES `vendedor` (`id_vendedor`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `depositoxvendedor_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id_local`) REFERENCES `local` (`id_local`);

--
-- Filtros para la tabla `lado`
--
ALTER TABLE `lado`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `lado_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_punto`) REFERENCES `punto` (`id_punto`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `lado_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id_local`) REFERENCES `local` (`id_local`);

--
-- Filtros para la tabla `manguera`
--
ALTER TABLE `manguera`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `manguera_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_lado`) REFERENCES `lado` (`id_lado`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `manguera_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id_articulo`) REFERENCES `articulo` (`id_articulo`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `manguera_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`id_local`) REFERENCES `local` (`id_local`);

--
-- Filtros para la tabla `punto`
--
ALTER TABLE `punto`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `punto_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_local`) REFERENCES `local` (`id_local`);

--
-- Filtros para la tabla `puntoxvendedor`
--
ALTER TABLE `puntoxvendedor`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `puntoxvendedor_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_punto`) REFERENCES `punto` (`id_punto`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `puntoxvendedor_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id_vendedor`) REFERENCES `vendedor` (`id_vendedor`);

--
-- Filtros para la tabla `vendedor`
--
ALTER TABLE `vendedor`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `vendedor_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_local`) REFERENCES `local` (`id_local`);
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

```
select C.fecha_contometro as fecha ,C.turno_contometro as turno,V.nombre_vendedor as vendedor, 
sum(DV.monto_depositoxvendedor) as deposito,
sum((C.final_contometro-C.inicial_contometro)*C.precio_articulo) as contometria
from contometro C 
inner join vendedor V on C.id_vendedor=V.id_vendedor
inner join depositoxvendedor DV on DV.id_vendedor=V.id_vendedor
GROUP BY C.id_vendedor
```

[The query gives me this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xH3Zv.png)

the result should be:

| Date | turno | Vendedor | Deposito | Contometria |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 28/11/2023 | 1 | VENDEDOR 1 AVENTURERO | 250.00 | 354.00 |

Comment: I doubt your SQL will run unless there is very MySQL specific syntax. How can you group by only c.id_vendedor and have only two aggregate values but also display two more which are not included in the group by?

Comment: Any idea what I have to change to make it work the way I want?

Comment: Maybe I have to change the structure of the tables to give me the expected result?
I am open to changes in structure.

Comment: Three tables are inner joined using id_vendedor but table `contometro` only has id_vendedor=1. How do you get the  expected output including VENDEDOR 2 ?

Comment: It was my mistake, not putting the other VENDEDOR. What I want is for it not to add up several times, I correct my post

Comment: @Julian That's a feature/bug of MySQL 5.x and MariaDB as well. It generated unpredictable results.

Comment: @The Impaler Isn't that determined by whether the system variable `SQL_MODE` has the value ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY in it ?

Comment: @TheImpaler thanks and good to know. I would argue that relying on such a "feature" is a good idea and if the SQL_MODE mentioned by blabla_bingo exist I think that should always be switched ON

Comment: @Julian, I added further info regarding that in the answer.

Comment: I receive error FUNCTION any_value does not exist. I am using mysql version 5.6 and I am on a shared server in which I am not allowed to update the mysql version

Comment: @blabla_bingo Yes, it's turned off by default in MySQL 5.x and on by default in 8.x. It was a bad idea in the first place, since I don't see use for a query that  generates changing, unpredictable results every time is run.

Comment: any other solution to get the required result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select  DV.fecha_depositoxvendedor as date,  turno, V.nombre_vendedor as vendedor,
sum(DV.monto_depositoxvendedor) as deposito,
any_value(C.contometria) as contometria -- The aggregation function any_value makes the syntax right but logically uncenessary, as the aggregation is already done in the derived table C. Use min or max if function any_value is not available.
from  
    (select id_vendedor , turno_contometro as turno, sum((final_contometro-inicial_contometro)*precio_articulo) as contometria
    from contometro 
    group by id_vendedor, turno) C
inner join vendedor V on C.id_vendedor=V.id_vendedor
inner join depositoxvendedor DV on DV.id_vendedor=V.id_vendedor
group by vendedor, date, turno  
;

-- result
+------------+-------+-----------------------+----------+-------------+
| date       | turno | vendedor              | deposito | contometria |
+------------+-------+-----------------------+----------+-------------+
| 2023-11-28 |     1 | VENDEDOR 1 AVENTURERO |   250.00 |     354.000 |
+------------+-------+-----------------------+----------+-------------+
```

Note, the answer is written with the SQL_MODE value  `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` specified, which DOES NOT allow the select list to have *nonaggregated columns that are neither named in the GROUP BY clause nor are functionally dependent on (uniquely determined by) GROUP BY columns*. When we have the value in SQL_MODE, if we delete the `turno` from the group by list at the end of the main query, an error occurs.

```
select  DV.fecha_depositoxvendedor as date,  turno, V.nombre_vendedor as vendedor,
sum(DV.monto_depositoxvendedor) as deposito,
any_value(C.contometria) as contometria -- The aggregation function any_value makes the syntax right but logically uncenessary, as the aggregation is already done in the derived table C. 
from  
    (select id_vendedor , turno_contometro as turno, sum((final_contometro-inicial_contometro)*precio_articulo) as contometria
    from contometro 
    group by id_vendedor, turno) C
inner join vendedor V on C.id_vendedor=V.id_vendedor
inner join depositoxvendedor DV on DV.id_vendedor=V.id_vendedor
group by vendedor, date
;

-- result:
ERROR 1055 (42000): Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'C.turno' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

And if we remove the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`, it will run without fail.

Finally, it's probably beyond my concerns over the business logic, but I suppose the join condition using `id_vendedor` only is less satisfactory. Shouldn't we consider further join condition such as matching date and turno between table `contometro` and `depositoxvendedor` ?

Comment: On the same shift there are several vendedor. that's why one per id_vendedor.

Comment: I receive error FUNCTION any_value does not exist

Comment: I receive error FUNCTION any_value does not exist. I am using mysql version 5.6 and I am on a shared server in which I am not allowed to update the mysql version

Comment: any other solution to get the required result?

Comment: @Christyan Rodriguez  , If function `any_value` is not available, using `min` or `max` is fine in this case.

Comment: can you give the code example

Comment: @Christyan Rodriguez , you literally replace the exact word `any_value` with `max` in the code.

Comment: Right, this worked. thank you so much. This is how my code looked.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that all the `JOINing` occurs before any aggregation )sic as `SUM()`).  This may get the correct sums.  (Note that it obviates the need for `GROUP BY`.)

```
SELECT  V.nombre_vendedor as vendedor,
        ( SELECT sum(DV.monto_depositoxvendedor)
            FROM depositoxvendedor DV
            WHERE DV.id_vendedor=V.id_vendedor ) as deposito,
        ( SELECT  sum((C.final_contometro - C.inicial_contometro) * C.precio_articulo)
              ) as contometria
    FROM vendedor V
```

I don't know how to deal with `C.fecha_contometro` and `C.turno_contometro` because these are multiple fechas per vendor, etc.  Perhaps `MAX(C.fecha_contometro)`?

Comment: it gives me this error
Something is wrong in your syntax near '' on line 7
and it shows me this code that it adds at the end
LIMIT 0, 25

Comment: @ChristyanRodriguez - Sorry, I left out a right-paren.

Comment: Column 'C.final_contometro' in field list is unknown